# Pion decay exercise in Griffiths books

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I have questions about pion decay problem.

In Griffith "Introduction to Elementary Particles" 1st edition, 1987, question number 10.10 :

Analyze $\pi^-$ decay as a scattering process, using the methods of Example 7.8 and 
Section 9.3. Calculate the decay rate, and, by comparing your answer with the 
one in the text, obtain the formula for $f_\pi$ in terms of $|\psi(0)|^2$. **Assume $m_u=m_d=m$.**

Answers : $f_\pi^2=\frac{4\hbar^3 m }{m_\pi^2 c}\cos^2\theta_c|\psi(0)|^2$

But in the second edition of Griffith's book, question number 9.14 is slightly different from previous edition (the bold texts are the differences) :

Analyze $\pi^-$ decay as a scattering process, using the methods of Example 7.8 and 
Section 8.5. Calculate the decay rate, and, by comparing your answer with the 
one in the text, obtain the formula for $f_\pi$ in terms of $|\psi(0)|^2$. **Take the quarks to be massless.**

Answers : $f_\pi^2=\frac{2\hbar^3}{3c}\frac{(2m_\pi^2 +m_l^2) }{m_\pi m_l^2}\cos^2\theta_c|\psi(0)|^2$

I know how to solve the second edition problem, but I couldn't figure out the first edition.

Could anyone help me to figure out the first edition way of thinking?